# I can't use my data variable with VueJS and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want to show a message on my page with VueJS, but Laravel doesn't want to show it and sends me an error message :

```
Use of undefined constant message - assumed 'message' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

My index.blade.php :

```
<a v-bind:href="link"> {{ message }} </a>
```

My app.js :

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello world',
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Your error appears because Laravel Blade tries to parse `{{ message }}` as PHP code. Laravel Blade and VueJS are sharing the same `{{ }}` syntax for showing variables.

In order to tell Blade that your `{{ message }}` is not PHP code, you either need to do this :

```html
<a v-bind:href="link"> @{{ message }} </a>
```

or, if you have lots of VueJS code, you can surround your HTML with this :

```html
@verbatim
    <a v-bind:href="link"> {{ message }} </a>
@endverbatim
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks)

Comment: Isn't work too it's write {{ message }} instead of hello world :'(

Comment: @ValentinLeguy Make sure your `<a>` tag is indeed inside an element with the ID `#app`, as you defined in app.js

Answer (score 1):

```
<a v-bind:href="link"> @{{ message }} </a>
```